# ASP Gridview slows with record count over 150 after adding TimeSpan

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, gridview, timespan

My gridview works fine with 900+ records. But I added a new column that calculates days in a date per row. It takes today's date and calculates the number of days since the date that is returned from the DB.

Abstract EXAMPLE:

```
-------------------------------
| Something | Date      | Days |
-------------------------------
|    A      | 3/1/2015  | 2    |
|    B      | 3/1/2014  | 365  |
-------------------------------
```

I ***OnRowDataBound*** each row to the RowDataBound to customize the label text

```
protected void gvView_RowDataBound (object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {

            Label     daysInCycle   = (Label)e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("lblDays");

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
                DataRowView ThisRow = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

                if (ThisRow.Row.Field<DateTime?> ("MyDate").HasValue) {
                    TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - ThisRow.Row.Field<DateTime>("MyDate");
                    daysInCycle.Text = ts.Days.ToString();
                } else {
                    daysInCycle.Text = "N/A";
                }
            }
        }
```

And in my gridview in the .aspx file

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Days">
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label ID="lblDays" runat="server" Text="NA"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Any ideas on why my gridview / IE would become unresponsive and just hang after the inclusion of the **TimeSpan**? If I take out the TimeSpan calculation, the gridview returns to its normal responsive self.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything that would cause a hang.   But you don't need to to create a new instance of Now() in each `RowDataBound` event.

Declare a datetime variable as a member variable of the page class:

```
DateTime TimeStamp;
```

In the `DataBinding` event set the variable to DateTime.Now:

```
TimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
```

Then in `RowDataBound` use the variable instead of the call to Now().

```
Label daysInCycle   = (Label)e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("lblDays");
daysInCycle.Text = "N/A";

if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
    DataRowView ThisRow = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

    if (ThisRow.Row.Field<DateTime?> ("MyDate").HasValue) {
        TimeSpan ts = TimeStamp - ThisRow.Row.Field<DateTime>("MyDate");
        daysInCycle.Text = ts.Days.ToString();
    } 
}
```